# How to manually add artifacts in jenkins?

Tags: ios, jenkins, ipa, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-cli

I am using shell script to create a build but that falls outside of the Jenkins Directory and so I am unable to add it as Artifact.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I understand you want to change the folder where are you creating the artifact instead the workspace folder from your job? what kind of task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just copy the .ipa file to jenkins workspace using shell command and thereby you can add the file as Artifact

1.*Add a build step to execute the shell command*

[image]

2.*Enter the shell command to copy the file from outside to Jenkins workspace*

[image]

*Here **$WORKSPACE** is Predefined environment variable of JENKINS which has the path of jenkins workspace and $PathToIpa is the variable created by you which should have the path of the ipa file*

3. *You have to archive the file as Artifact so go to "Add post-build action" and choose "Archive the artifacts"*

[image]

4.*In the files to archive you can give name of the file or else you can do wild card selection also.*

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: $WORKSPACE variable doesn't exist

Comment: Can this be used for Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Yes , I did it for Jenkins.